# XNA - Windows Aero Effect is no more if you toggle full screen

Tags: aero, xna-4.0

i am using `togglefullscreen()` function to ofc toggle between window mode & full screen for my application(game).

When i run the game in window mode, the title bar has the Windows Aero Effect of Win7 as it should be, but when i go full-screen and come back to window mode, then there is no more Aero Effect in window title bar, just a normal title bar

[image]

Similarly if i start the Game in full screen mode and then toghle to window mode, there is no more aero effect. Why is that happening & how to get back aero effect

Comment: Games generally do turn Aero's features off when fullscreened, but it usually goes back on afterwards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows disables Aero because while you're inside a fullscreen app, the user usually doesn't see the title bar or task bar so it's just a waste of time to compute the 'good' graphics (transparency for example). If Aero doesn't restart after you close your program, then you can make a .bat file like so:

```
@ECHO off
net stop uxsms
net start uxsms
```

This will stop the service controlling aero, and then restart it (which always brings back the scheme if it should be there. (Obviously this is not in c#, but if you can do the same thing using the `Process` class, or by starting `cmd.exe` with some arguments. (`"/C"` will allow you to call commands from `cmd.exe`).